# Как посчитать количество записей с одинаковым значением в таблице по определенному условию?

Tags: sql, count

Есть таблица marks(idStudent, idSubject, mark). Каким образом можно посчитать количество студентов, у которых есть хотя бы одна двойка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Показывает самых заядлых двоечников с сортировкой по убыванию

```
select idStudent, count(*)
from marks m
where m.mark = 2
group by idStudent
order by 2 desc
```

А тут двоечники с группировкой по предметам

```
select idStudent, idSubject, count(*)
from marks m
where m.mark = 2
group by idStudent, idSubject
order by 3 desc
```

Comment: Хотелось бы количество, а не список уникальных)

Comment: Да пожалуйста! :). Ответ обновлен